# Request for tag merge: 'argument' and 'arguments'

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

It looks like 'arguments' has a thorough description and more questions (1285 vs 321). Unless there's a good reason to keep the singular and the plural, should these be merged?

[argument](/questions/tagged/argument) [arguments](/questions/tagged/arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Completed: [argument](/questions/tagged/argument) --> [arguments](/questions/tagged/arguments)